# Android - ImageView blank (xml only)

Tags: android, imageview

I am having a weird issue on my new project, I just cant display an image on my activity.
The ImageView shows a blank square.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYHuP.png)

If I try with a black background and a picture with transparency, I can see the picture that appears in white even if it is supposed to be colored.
But if I try with a multi colored picture with no transparency, it just shows a blank square.

I tried on emulator and phone with the exact same result.

I checked all the related posts on Stackoverflow without any working solution.

My src :

I added a small picture in res/drawable/test2.png

Here is my (very basic) activity code / activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/test2"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity :
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <application
            android:name=".Application"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
                android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my build file:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.myappid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: share your `test2.png`

Comment: Exactly try with other picture

Comment: @HongDuan  I tried with maybe 10 different pictures, different formats (jpg, bmp, mostly png) with transparency or not. Always the same: everything that is not transparent is blank. I just tried with this pic (https://www.shareicon.net/data/256x256/2016/09/16/829667_nature_512x512.png) and I get a blank circle

Comment: There must be some hidden differences in your project, you'd better share a complete project which can reproduce this issue, you can publish it to you github so we can help you.

Comment: @HongDuan I solved the issue, see my comment below. Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my bad I just failed at copy / paste.

I had this in my style.xml:

```
<item name="android:tint">@color/colorLight</item>
```

Removing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using

> android:scaleType:"centreInside"

to see if this is a scaling issue? Also, what is the dimens of the image?

Comment: Added android:scaleType="centerInside" on the ImageView but still blank

Comment: did you check the dimens and size of the image?

Answer (score 0):

I would use glide to manage pictures honestly! It's gonna be easier in the long run to manage picture that way!

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Also make sure that you set the following code for a cache optimization

```
  @Override public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
      builder.setMemoryCache(new MemoryCacheAdapter());
  }
```

Comment: Doesnt really solve the issue but it looks very interesting, i might use it in the future